Supremum of nineteen hundred eighty-two derivative of some function
Prove that $$\sup\left|\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{(1982)}\right|=\frac{1}{1983}$$
It is $1982$ derivative of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$. I tried to find a general formula for n-th derivative of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$, but I couldn't do this. I don't know what approach I should take

$\frac{\sin x}{x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$ so $\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{(2n)}  = (-1)^n \frac{1}{2n+1}$.

@athos thank you so much!
